# Validation errors showing after form submit in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-application, flutter-getx

The code for form field and the the submit button is given below

This is the code for the submit button

```
Visibility(
visible: controller.getActionBtnVisibility(),
child: Material(
type: MaterialType.transparency,
child: InkWell(
highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
onTap: ()  {
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

                        final isValid = controller
                            .jointControllerFormKey.currentState!
                            .validate();
    
                        if (!isValid) {
                          return;
                        } else {
                          controller.addBeneficiary();
                       //   controller.clearJointAccount();
                          //
                          // await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
                          //
                          controller.jointControllerFormKey.currentState!
                              .reset();
                          controller.clearJointAccount();
    
    
                        }
```

This is the code for the textformfield  rest form fields are almost same

```
  TextFormField(
                      controller: controller.lastName,
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                      validator: (value) =>
                          value == "" ? Strings.required.tr : null,
                      // keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                      // inputFormatters: [
                      //   FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                      // ],
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white),
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "",
                          hintStyle:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white70),
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              width: 1.2,
                              color: DarkThemeColors.headingTextColor,
                            ), //<-- SEE HERE
                          ),
                          disabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              width: 1.2,
                              color: DarkThemeColors.headingTextColor,
                            ), //<-- SEE HERE
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              width: 1.2,
                              color: DarkThemeColors.headingTextColor,
                            ), //<-- SEE HERE
                          ),
                          isDense: true,
                          isCollapsed: true,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.1)),
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                    ),
```

The validation errors must not show after the form is submitted.  But when the for is submitted the validation errors for the first three fields are shown. rest two are not shown

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Could you write up what you want?

Comment: When I validate the form after filling all the fields the from is validated and the data also saved where i want. But the validation error through validator property of the Textform fields appear below the fields

I just want that the validation error do not show after the form is validated

Comment: As far as i got it. you want the textfield to validated when you validate the form with the button click and not when the user entering data in it. Than you just need to remove the parameter `autovalidateMode` from your textfields, It's disable by default so you just remove it. currently you set it to `onUserInteraction` that mean it will start validating the field when user it entering data, And it will be validated with each and every entering character.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was clearing the form fields after the

`formKey.currentState!.reset()`
that was causing the validation error to appear after text fields are cleared.
And if I tried to used before the
`formKey.currentState!.reset`
the fields were not being cleared.
Later on I realised that this was happening because of `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();`

Changing it to `FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();`  Solved my problem.